# Deleting Row by Primary Key - SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have ran into a bit of a problem regarding deleting a row by primary key in my android application that has a background database of SQLite.

At the minute I have 6 line types. e.g. S1, S2, S3 etc. I can only have 6 lines at one time and therefore I only have 6 rows in my database. Beside each button on my application I have an "X" button and when they click on say the X button beside S1 I want the database to delete the row with primary key "S1".

I think there is a quick solution but ive tried to manipulate my query many different ways and cant get the correct answer.

Here is some code I have:

DB Helper:

```
 public void deleteProgressBar4() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_2 + "=", new String[]{"S1"});
    return;
}
```

> COL_2 is the LineType by the way..

X button code :

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                   myDb.deleteProgressBar4();
                                                   Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Line S1 Cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                               }
                                           });
```

Can anyone see the mistake that I am making in the delete function? here is the error I am getting when I run this:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM pharma_tracker_table WHERE LINETYPE=
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
>                         at com.almac.tracker.DatabaseHelper.deleteProgressBar4(DatabaseHelper.java:141)
>                         at com.almac.tracker.Dashboard$6$1.onClick(Dashboard.java:219)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>   Application terminated.

Thanks!

Comment: use `" = ?"`, not `"="`

Comment: Thanks @pskink! that worksss

Answer (score -2):

Just Replace with you table name and column name

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long i =db.delete("tableName", "column Name = ?", new String[]{String.valueof(Id)});
```